# How to make a accurate scroll zone?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I would like to set an accurate scroll zone for my divs, here's where I want it to be :
[scroll zone in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p53Kk.png)

So I'll have 4 divs maximum, and so it must contain a total of 10 rectangles per category (concentration, boost...)

I tried to set a scroll bar with a wrapper but I can't make it work clean. Here's what I got so far:

[what i got so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaMC1.png)

My code :

```
.containerfocuslist {
    margin-top: 4rem;
    height: 650px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: What's your actual problem? You seem to have created a scrollable area, so it'll be easy to change its size to be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Element size and scrolling
There are many JavaScript properties that allow us to read information about element width, height and other geometry features.

We often need them when moving or positioning elements in JavaScript.

Sample element
As a sample element to demonstrate properties we’ll use the one given below:

```
<div id="example">
  ...Text...
</div>
<style>
  #example {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 25px solid #E8C48F;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
</style>
```

It has the border, padding and scrolling. The full set of features. There are no margins, as they are not the part of the element itself, and there are no special properties for them.

For more information [click here](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll)